# Links being hide when page opened

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, hyperlink, modx-evolution

If you open first page of http://www.sundayrock.ru website in Chrome Browser all links on the main page are hidden (top menu with knobs).
But if you hover on a link, it appears. After loading second page everything is ok. Even if you just click on any point (not a link), all links will appear.
Site works on modx.
Please see print screen of the bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUVAw.jpg

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am looking it on chrome 33 windows 7 it looks fine! is it possible for you to post screenshot link or describe more

Comment: Is it your backlinking strategy ? ;) It works on chrome 33 windows 8.1

Comment: I think it is some design issue

Comment: My question is how to fix it.
It is not my backlinking strategy :) In some browsers and os it looks fine. Issue screened here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IUVAw.jpg

Comment: Well many thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/users/771873/kjetilh who discovered this way of fixing this problem.

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        if (/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
            $('body').css('opacity', '1.0') 
        }
    })
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a better answer, you can put

```
$(document).ready(function(){}
  jQuery('.menu li a').css('text-decoration', 'none');
)};
```

Comment: Chad, i tried it in two ways

1. With google lib (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js) and it fixed the problem! But the other side is that slider that placed lower braked.

2. With my lib on host jquery-1.4.4.min.js
Slider broke again, but menu problem still remain.